# how to do dynamic xml in angular 4/5 application

Tags: angular

Assume: example.com is a running angular 4 application. 
and routes like /product, /category exist, how would I do /products.XML, /category.xml as a route which will show the dynamic XML for the same.

Comment: You wouldn't need Angular to do that. You would directly get the data from the REST services of the backend, that woud return XML.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested by JB Nizet, you can get the data from the backend.

But because angular has already taken over the routing etc, you will need to update your angular router and define component which would be actived on the routes like `category.xml` and ask the server for the raw XML data and then display it.

I am afraid that you can not do something like `**.xml` in the route definition, but on the other hand, I've never tried that. All the examples show `**` as the wildcard route, which matches ANY url.

You can read extensively about router here https://vsavkin.com/the-powerful-url-matching-engine-of-angular-router-775dad593b03